# Zend Framework Filter Input ENUM

Tags: zend-framework, filter-input

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.3 for a project I'm developing.

I use Filter Input and need to make sure the value is within certain values (ENUM). (e.g. frequency must be either 'instantly', 'daily' or 'weekly').

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would use a validator to do this

```
  $validator = new Zend_Validate_InArray(array('ENUM1' => 'value 1',
                                               'ENUM2' => 'value 1',
                                               'ENUM3' => 'value 3'));
   $element->addValidator($validator);
```

Comment: I've used this solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly you may be looking some thing like  this:-
You can use input form validators , if  the value is to be among certain value.

// create text input for age
// should contain only integer values between 1 and 100

```
$age = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('age');
$age  ->setLabel('Age:')
      ->setOptions(array('size' => '4'))
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->addValidator('Int')  //must be an Integer
      ->addValidator('Between', false, array(1,100)); //from 1 to 100
```

The same but just using Zend_Validate class.

```
// create text input for age
// should contain only integer values between 1 and 100


 $age = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('age');
 $age->setLabel('Age:')
    ->setOptions(array('size' => '4'))
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Int())
    ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Between(1,100));
```